# Did Rails Routing change the way it handles the params[:path]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, rails-routing

I recently upgraded a site from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 1.9.2, and from Rails 3.0.x to 3.2.x. I noticed that some of my legacy urls weren't being handled correctly anymore, and wanted to diagnose the issue.

Here's what I noticed.

`http://myapp.com/links/oldlink.html` had, in my old app, provided a `params[:path]` of `/links/oldlink.html`, but *now* is providing `links/oldlink`. So it's dropping the leading forwardslash as well as the file extension.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on here? Of course I can manually change the legacy strings in my database to also drop their forward slashes and file extensions, but that seems like a hacky solution, and I want to make sure I understand the underlying principles that account for this change in the Rails routing behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not answer but a workaround: `request.fullpath.split("?")[0]` will return the path without the parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in your routes.rb

```
match '/foo', :to => redirect('/foo.html')
```